# Inequality of conditioned expectation including geometric distributions

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $Y$ be any $\mathbb{N}_0$-valued random variable. Further, let $0 \leq s \leq t < 1$ and $X^{(s)}$ have geometric law $\text{Geo}(1-s)$ and $X^{(t)}$ geometric law $\text{Geo}(1-t)$, i.e. $$ P(X^{(s)} = k) = (1-s)s^{k-1} $$
for $k \geq 1$. Assume the random variables $Y, X^{(s)}, X^{(t)}$ to be independent.

I am thinking about whether the following holds true:
$$ E[ Y \mid Y \geq X^{(s)} ] \leq E [ Y \mid Y \geq X^{(t)}]$$
for all $0 \leq s \leq t < 1$.

I have the suspicion that this holds true independently of the law of $Y$ or maybe only, if $Y$ has infinite support. My intuition is that for $k$ large, $E[ Y \mid Y \geq k ]$ is close to $k$ and $EX^{(s)} \leq E X^{(t)}$. But it might indeed be false, then I am interested in a counter example or any ideas about what restriction have to be made.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\N{\mathbb{N}}\def\peq{\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{}}$First, $E(Y \mid Y \geqslant X(s)) = \dfrac{E(Y I_{\{Y \geqslant X(s)\}})}{P(Y \geqslant X(s))}$. Since\begin{gather*}
P(Y \geqslant X(s)) = \sum_{n = 1}^∞ \sum_{k = 1}^n P(Y = n,\ X(s) = k) = \sum_{n = 1}^∞ \sum_{k = 1}^n P(Y = n) P(X(s) = k)\\
= \sum_{n = 1}^∞ P(Y = n) \sum_{k = 1}^n P(X(s) = k) = \sum_{n = 1}^∞ (1 - s^n) P(Y = n),
\end{gather*}\begin{gather*}
E(Y I_{\{Y \geqslant X(s)\}}) = \sum_{n = 1}^∞ \sum_{k = 1}^n n P(Y = n,\ X(s) = k) = \sum_{n = 1}^∞ \sum_{k = 1}^n n P(Y = n) P(X(s) = k)\\
= \sum_{n = 1}^∞ n P(Y = n) \sum_{k = 1}^n P(X(s) = k) = \sum_{n = 1}^∞ n (1 - s^n) P(Y = n),
\end{gather*}
then$$
E(Y \mid Y \geqslant X(s)) = \frac{\sum\limits_{n = 1}^∞ n (1 - s^n) P(Y = n)}{\sum\limits_{n = 1}^∞ (1 - s^n) P(Y = n)},
$$
and analogously,$$
E(Y \mid Y \geqslant X(t)) = \frac{\sum\limits_{n = 1}^∞ n (1 - t^n) P(Y = n)}{\sum\limits_{n = 1}^∞ (1 - t^n) P(Y = n)}.
$$
Now the inequality is proved in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3657170) to [Monotonicity of a fraction combined with series (related to probability distributions)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3648982).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am interested in a self-contained proof that does not rely on the question "Monotonicity of a fraction combined with series (related to probability distributions)", since I would like to do the opposite and prove the statement in "Monotonicity of a fraction combined with series (related to probability distributions)" by showing the above inequality.

Comment: @FelixP. It's unclear what you meant by “doing the opposite” since my proof shows that the two questions are equivalent, i.e. it “proves the opposite”. Do you want an alternative proof of the series inequality or what?

Comment: I am looking for a probabilistic proof of the series inequality via the inequality I stated in this thread.

Comment: @FelixP. - I think Saad has a good point.  The two problems are equivalent (as I showed in my other Answer), so you really should have (1) mentioned the equivalence and also (2) stated that you wanted a different proof, preferably using more "probabilistic" reasoning instead of algebraic manipulation.